Convert Time Input in Decimal Format - Excel Formula or VBA
I have hundreds of rows of time entered as "min.sec" (10.15) in column A. Column B converts these times into "min.% of min". for example; 10.15 is being converted into 10.25. 8.30 would be converted into 8.50 etc. I need this conversion to happen in column B and cannot add any additional columns to the worksheet.
My current formula has almost got me there but i have found an issue when the minutes are single digits sometimes...... If i have 24.16 in A2, it converts to 24.2666 but when i put in 4.16 in A2 it converts to 14. I say sometimes because i also see instances where 9.10 in column A is properly converting into 9.17 in column B. So the formula does appear to be working properly, but only sometimes.
Here is my current formula in B2:
=(LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1)*1)+IF(LEFT(RIGHT(A2,FIND(".",A2)))=".",(RIGHT(A2,FIND(".",A2))*100/60),(RIGHT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1)*100/60))
Does anyone see the error in the formula? id prefer an updated formula but if there is a easier VBA method i am ok with that as well.
Thanks for any help!

Use INT and MOD to split the value:
=INT(A1)+MOD(A1,1)/0.6



Thanks @Scott Craner !!! So much simpler than the rabbit hole I was going down.
